# How to place a div beside input box on focus?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

I have a scenario,that I used css for extending search box on focus,when I focussed on search box then the search box must decrease and the cancel button must be placed beside of search box.

Css:

```
.clrble .frmcntr {
background:url("images/search.png") no-repeat 110px center;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 4px;
border: medium none;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 20px;
font-family:SFUIDisplay;
padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
width: 95%;
background-color:rgba(247, 247, 247, 1);
 }

: content-box;
font-size: 100%;

.clrble .frmcntr:focus {
    width: 70%;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #66CC75;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
    background-color:rgba(247, 247, 247, 1);
    background:url("images/search.png") no-repeat  10px center;
    padding-left:40px;
}

.clrble .frmcntr {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-box-sizing

}
```

Here is my plunker link:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Z7mfglWEoDyjbDfFDbLM?p=preview

And the expected output will be like this:

[image]

Is it possible with Angularjs or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution would be to position the div you want absolutely. Then on focus of the input, make the div visible or slide it into view;

Using your plunk, add the following CSS:

```
.clrble{
  position: relative;
}
.frmcntr:focus + .btn{
  display: block;
}

.btn{display: none; position: absolute; right: 0;}
```

and here's the HTML:

```
<div class="clrble">
    <input type="text"  placeholder="Search" class="frmcntr">
    <div class="btn">button here</div>               
</div>
```

It's not perfect, but i think it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: @ehel Thank for your help,here is the problem the button is placing after that div not in the same div,so how to give bootsrap css classes on hover.

Comment: it is in the same div (.frmcntr) - just give the button the bootstrap classes you'd like to give it (not just on hover, but always): `<div class="btn btn-bootstrap-class1 ...">button here</div>  `

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `blur` event for the input and the `mousedown` event as mousedown event fires before the blur event.

```js
var mouseDown = false;

$('input').blur(function() {
    if(mouseDown) // cancel the blur event
    {
        $('input').focus();
        mouseDown = false;
    }

});


$('#cancelBtn').mousedown(function(){
  mouseDown = true;
  console.log('Button Clicked');
});

$('input').focus(function(){
  $('#cancelBtn').css('display', 'block');
});

$('input').focusout(function(){
  $('#cancelBtn').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.clrble .frmcntr {
    background:url("images/search.png") no-repeat 110px center;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: medium none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
 font-family:SFUIDisplay;
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    width: 95%;
 background-color:rgba(247, 247, 247, 1);
  float:left;
}

.clrble .frmcntr:focus {
    width: 70%;
 text-align: left;
    background-color: green;
    border-color: #66CC75;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
 background-color:rgba(247, 247, 247, 1);
 background:url("images/search.png") no-repeat  10px center;
 padding-left:40px;
}

.clrble .frmcntr {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    font-size: 100%;
}

#cancelBtn {
color:blue;
float:left;
font-weight:bold;
display:none;
padding:5px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <div class="clrble">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="frmcntr">
                  <div id="cancelBtn">Cancel</div>           
       </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I updated my code to display it besides the box using float:left. Please check now

Comment: hey thank you it works for me,but facing small issue.

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing??

Comment: but the issue is,I need to set the search box to its original postion on-click of cancel,but now when I get out of focus it is setting to actual position

Comment: @bpbsr I have solved your problem please check the answer i have updated it.

Comment: on buttonclick i have to remove the focus,not outside.

Answer (score 0):

with float property you can mange the side by side positions.

use `float:left;` css property for you textbox class and that will work for your requirement and the placement of button also can be handle by css also.

css for textbox

```
.clrble .frmcntr {
background:url("images/search.png") no-repeat 110px center;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 4px;
border: medium none;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 20px;
font-family:SFUIDisplay;
padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
width: 95%;
background-color:rgba(247, 247, 247, 1);
float:left;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can just hide and show a span with 'cancel' in it.

```css
/* Styles go here */

.clrble .frmcntr {
  background: url("images/search.png") no-repeat 110px center;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: medium none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: SFUIDisplay;
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  width: 95%;
  background-color: rgba(247, 247, 247, 1);
}

.clrble .frmcntr:focus {
  width: 70%;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #66CC75;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109, 207, 246, .5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109, 207, 246, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109, 207, 246, .5);
  background-color: rgba(247, 247, 247, 1);
  background: url("images/search.png") no-repeat 10px center;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.clrble .frmcntr {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.clrble {
  position: relative;
}

.frmcntr:focus+.btn {
  display: block;
}

.btn {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.cancel {
  visibility: hidden;
  color: blue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.frmcntr:focus + .cancel {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="clrble">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="frmcntr">
    <span class="cancel">Cancel</span>
    <span class="btn">button here</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but the issue is,I need to set the search box to its original postion on-click of cancel,but now when I get out of focus it is setting to actual position

Comment: @bpbsr Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by 'actual position'? Everything returns to start when I click out of focus...

Comment: but i need to handle with cancel button